# Run Perl in Editplus

Tags: perl, editplus

I have configured to execute perl in my editplus software and I am able to do that successfully, but the strange problem I am facing is, **It takes 15 seconds of time to execute even if it is just 1 line script with a print statement**. When I have tried to install the same version of active perl in other laptops, it doesn't take so much of time for execution. I get the below output when I run the script

```
Output completed (15 sec consumed) - Normal Termination
```

I have tried re-installing other versions etc but the problem persists.

Please let me know if any of you have faced the same problem.

Comment: Looking at the [features of EditPlus](http://www.editplus.com/feature.html), I don't see anything about IDE capabilities.  How are you executing Perl code via EditPlus?

Comment: with the menu item Tools -> Configure User Tools > Tools > User Tools , for command: giving perl exe path, for arguement give as $(FileName) and initial directory  give as $(FileDir)...Then if you say Ctrl+1 for a perl script...we can execute perl....My problem is it is taking 15 seconds to execute

Comment: I presume that it's not taking anywhere near that long on the command line?  If not, then my hunch is that EditPlus isn't built to be an IDE.  However, I'm not completely certain, since I'm not familiar with EditPlus.

Comment: Near command line, it doesnot take that much time...only when i try to execute in editplus it is taking that long....But in my personal laptop...it doesnot take that long....I am not sure why it is happening only in this system...

Comment: Then it seems as though EditPlus is adding a lot of overhead.  Perhaps you should try a genuine IDE such as [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/).

Comment: I suggest you to check out : http://strawberryperl.com/

Answer (score 0):

Editplus running a perl script runs excellently in the following environment:

- Windows 7
- EditPlus version 3.70
- Perl version 5.14.2, 64bit

The configuration for the user tool is:

- Menu Text => Run Perl Script
- Command => C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe
- Argument => "$(FilePath)"
- I leave Initial directory blank
- Action => Capture output
- Save => All open files